# How do I access the captured values from a RegExp like "/test/(\d+)"?

Tags: regex, dart

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get capture values from a regular expression! I thought it would be trivial but I'm just not seeing the results I'd expect.

Here's my code, which enumerates all groups and all matches, and prints them out:

```dart
var matches = new RegExp(r"/test/(\d+)").allMatches("/test/1");
matches.forEach((match) {
  for (var i = 0; i < match.groupCount; i++) {
    print(match.group(i));
  }
});
```

I would expect the output to include `/test/1` and `1`, however the only output is:

```dart
/test/1
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple; but I've been staring at [the docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.RegExp) for longer than is healthy, and can't spot what I'm missing :(

Comment: have you checked with the debugger? Btw, check this Code Generator section this code, it might help you http://regex101.com/r/wD5qN1/1. It escapes the forward slash `var re = /\/test\/(\d+)/;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find this a bit weird too but you have to change this

```dart
for (var i = 0; i <= match.groupCount; i++) {
                   ^
```

I don't really know but I interpret it this way. The actual groups start with 1 and `match.group(0)` is the entire match.

Comment: Urhg; you're right! The docs do say `If group is 0, returns the match of the pattern`, so the captures start at 1. Thanks!

Comment: This API is a bit weird; they should've added a `.fullMatch` property; and why is there no `Iterable` of groups? :( Having to do `new List.generate(match.groupCount, (i) => match.group(i + 1))` now!